# Sigma-algebra on $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ generated by $\epsilon = \{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\},\{4\}\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \{1,...,4\}$.
Let $\epsilon = \{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\},\{4\}\}$. Find $\sigma$ ($\epsilon$), generated by ($\epsilon$), and justify answer.

Could someone please give me some direction and help with this question please.

If I say $\{1,2\}=A$, $\{2,3\}=B$ and $\{4\}=C$ then $A^c=\{3,4\}$, $B^c=\{1,4\}$ and $C^c=\{1,2,3\}$.

I know that at least Omega and the empty set has to be part of the Sigma-algebra as well as the single partitions and their complements:

$\sigma(\epsilon)=\{\emptyset, \Omega, A, B, C, A^c, B^c, C^c\}$

Additionally, there has to be the union of the elements inside and this is the point I am not sure about. Are the following elements part of the Sigma-algebra as well (+ what about the complements?)

$$ A \cup B = \{1,2,3\}$$
$$ A \cup C = \{1,2,4\}$$
$$ B \cup C = \{2,3,4\} $$
$$ A \cup B \cup C = \Omega $$

Comment: Hint: Sigma algebras must also be closed under intersection (meaning the intersection of two sets must also be in the sigma algebra). Can you use this to show that $\sigma(\epsilon))$ is all of the subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: Have a look at the first 5 lines here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Definition_and_properties . Try to figure out if intersections need to be included as well and why. Then try to figure out which of the one-point subsets ($\{1\}, \{2\},\dots$ etc) will be in the sigma-algebra, and which won't. Then you may write your own answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interesting theorem – it will help you solve more exercises in this vein and it's a hint to prove that σ-algebra cannot be countable.

**Definition**. An *atom* of a σ-algebra $Σ$ is a non-void set $Á ∈ Σ$ that contains no other set of $Σ$.

**Example**. If a singleton belongs to σ-algebra, then it's an atom.

**Theorem**. If σ-algebra has $N \in \mathbb{N}$ atoms, then it has $2^N$ elements.

Proof. All other elements of σ-algebra are just unions of atoms. So we are actually asking a combinatorial question "In how many ways we can take unions of $N$ sets?" For $0 ≤ k ≤ N$, we have ${N \choose k}$ possible unions of $k$ sets (for $k=0$ we get an empty set, and for $k=N$ the whole space). In total
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N {N \choose k} = \text{number of all subsets of $N$ elements set} = 2^N.
$$
$\Box$

With this theorem, you can be sure that you haven't missed any element of σ-algebra.

**Answer**. In your exercise surely $\{4\}$ is an atom. But by taking intersections and differences you will discover that $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ are also atoms. Thus your σ-algebra will have $2^4$ elements and it has to be a power set.

---

**Bonus**. Intuitively σ-algebra generated by a finite family of sets $\mathcal{G}$ consists of sets made by all possible combinations (intersections, sums, complements, ...). Concretely, here are a Venn Diagrams for all possible combinations for two sets:

[image]

On the left, you have all possible operations "inside". On the right the complements. This gives you a systematic way to generate all elements of σ-algebra:

| "Inside" | Complements |
| --- | --- |
| $A$ | $A^c$ |
| $B$ | $B^c$ |
| $A \cup B$ | $(A \cup B)^c$ |
| $A \cap B$ | $(A \cap B)^c$ |
| $A \setminus B$ | $(A \setminus B)^c$ |
| $B \setminus A$ | $(B \setminus A)^c$ |
| $A \triangle B$ | $(A \triangle B)^c$ |

Add an empty set, a whole space, and voilà! But it gets much messier for more than two sets. And that's why you see only exercises with small generators .